# How to save fread outputs in the vector in R

Tags: r, file, fread

I need to save `f` data sets into the vector `allf`. This is my working code.

```
  allf <- vector(mode = "list", length = 100)
  for(i in 1:100)
  {   
    f = data.table::fread(paste0(dirPath, i, ".csv"))
    allf[[i]] <- f
  }
```

Now I want to make a parallel version of this code:

```
  allf <- vector(mode = "list", length = 100)
  allf <- foreach(i=1:100, .combine=rbind)
  {   
    f = data.table::fread(paste0(dirPath, i, ".csv"))
    f
  }
```

The problem is that all `f` elements are saved sequentially so that I cannot access each `f` using `allf[[i]]`.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Why are you trying to read files from a disk in parallel?

Comment: @joran: Would you suggest to use the first code?

Comment: Well, doing things in parallel can be faster (sometimes) because you have multiple processors. But presumably, you only have one disk, and each processor is talking to the same disk. They'd have to take turns.

Comment: @joran: well, using system.time I came to the conclusion that parallel implementation is much faster here. Don't know why. Therefore, I'd like to make it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is with the `snow` package, I was able to see gains over the regular load as well despite what we should expect as per @joran in the comments:

```
library(snow)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(rep("localhost", 4))
filenames <- Sys.glob(paste0(dirPath, "*.csv"))
f <- parLapply(cl, filenames, data.table::fread)
stopCluster(cl)
```